# How can I control access to storageclasses in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to restrict the ability of particular users to dynamically provision disks from storageclasses? Or, for example, only allowing particular namespaces to be able to use a storageclass?

Answer (score 2):

Fair warning: I haven't tested this!

StorageClass is just an API endpoint, and RBAC works by restricting access to those endpoints, so in theory this should work just fine:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: sc_access
rules:
- apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io", "core" ]
  resources: [ "storageclass" ]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

If that doesn't work, you might be able to restrict access directly via the NonResourceUrls option:

```
rules:
- nonResourceURLs: ["/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses"]
  verbs: ["get", "post"]
```

Comment: This restricts the ability to interact with storageclasses, but doesn't prevent a user from referencing a storageclass in a PVC once the storageclass has been created - I was more thinking of a situation where a cluster operator has created a load of strorageclasses and wants to lock down the use of them

Comment: If you bind these rules to the serviceaccount in a namespace, it should also apply for things like PVC creation as far as I know

Comment: Ah awesome, did not know that, will have a go a bit later

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - I created a SA that can only create PVCs and the user could still reference and use any storageclass using the `storageClassName` field

Comment: The main problem it seems is that the logic for dynamically provisioning a disk is in the controller-manager and so does not depend on the permissions of the user creating the original PVC object

Answer (score 0):

[Storage resource quota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#storage-resource-quota) can be used to restrict usage of storage classes